# how to get WFS later? GeoExt

Tags: javascript

Can u help me with WFS on GEOExt? Im read tutorial and see this code.

```
proxy: new GeoExt.data.ProtocolProxy({
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        url: "/geoserver/ows",
        version: "1.1.0",
        featureType: "parks",
        featureNS: "http://medford.opengeo.org",
        srsName: "EPSG:4326"
    })
})
```

After this i see this var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable features"); And dont understand how to creating a layer. So i have some questions.
1 How to get URL to wfs? (i use geoserver)
2 Whats mean featureType option.
3 And more important. This code is correct? I find it here http://workshops.opengeo.org/geoext/wfs/grid.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope its helps someone

```
             //WFS
                        var myStyle = OpenLayers.Util.extend({},
                            OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);
                        myStyle.strokeWidth = 1.5;
                        myStyle.strokeColor = "#ff0000";
                        myStyle.fillOpacity = 0.1;
                        OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "proxy.cgi?url=";
                        var renderer = OpenLayers.Util.getParameters(window.location.href).renderer;
                        renderer = (renderer) ? [renderer] : OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers;           
                        myVecLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Редактируемый участок", {
                            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save()],
                            style: myStyle,
                            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                                version: "1.0.0",
                                srsName:"EPSG:900913",
                                url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
                                featureType: "filedata",
                                featureNS: "http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite"
                            }),
                            renderers: renderer
                        })  
                        app.mapPanel.map.addLayers([myVecLayer]);
```

`featureType` name of layer in geoserver
`featureType` path to wokspace (also can be seen in geoserver)